# Loading multiple SVGs using Snap.load conflict with each other

Tags: html, css, svg, snap.svg

Originally, I was using one SVG file for all my elements, but it has grown large to the point where it takes about 10 seconds to load.

As a result, I would like to split that code into multiple SVG files so that I can prevent loading it all at once.

I have attempted this and was able to load them properly, but I am struggling with how I am supposed to format them properly in CSS so that they all function as they should when they are clicked on and displayed.

Here is some code for reference-

HTML:

```
<div class = "groupView">
    <svg viewBox='0 0 1800.9 1000.5' id='GroupView' preserveAspectRatio="none" height="100%" width="100%" x="0px" y="0px"></svg>
</div>

<div class = "statusIcons">
    <svg viewBox='0 0 1000 1000' id='StatusIcons' preserveAspectRatio="none" height="100%" width="100%" x="100px" y="100px">
        <circle id="MRLED0_0" class="" cx="169.9221" cy="142.224" r="3.4"/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var groupView = Snap('#GroupView');

Snap.load("/svg/GroupView.svg", function(f) {
    groupView.append(f);
});

var machBox = Snap('#MachBox');

Snap.load("/svg/MachBox.svg", function(g) {
    machBox.append(g);  
});
```

CSS:

```
div.groupView{
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;   /*relative  */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
} 

div.machBox{
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I have tried changing the position attributes to 'absolute' or 'fixed', but it seems there is an overlapping issue when I do that (the second SVG loads over the other) and prevents me from any clicking actions.

I also think there may be an issue with setting both classes with a width and height at 100%. I have it like that for correct positioning within the page, so I am not sure how I would change that. 
Has anybody dealt with this issue before?

Comment: It's not clear, do you 'need' the divs ? Can't you just have nested SVGs, as been as you used to have one svg ? Then load each and append (maybe place into a group for positioning) Maybe a jsfiddle example would be good.

Comment: @Ian if I was to remove the divs, would I not still need to apply CSS code on the SVGs for positioning? Can you explain what you mean by 'place into a group'?

Comment: Something like <svg><g id="g1' transform='translate(100,20)'><svg id='GroupView'>..(loadedfromfile)..</svg></g><g id='g2' transform='translate(90,20)'><svg id='Machbox'>...loadedfromfile..</svg></g></svg>  so you could start with <svg><g id='g1'><g id='g2')....then load svg part 1 and append to g1, load svg part 2 add to g2. If you need to position the group element g, you can just do it with a translate transform.